# In innoDB,If the repeatability of the secondary index is very high, will it greatly improve the count performance of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing, b-tree

As we know,mysql uses secondary index to improve the performance of count in innoDB.
If we have a unique secondary index and a index with many duplicate values，which index will mysql prefer to use to complete a whloe table count?

```
select count(*) from table
```

searched mysql document.

Comment: See EXPLAIN, it shows what index is used and is it used at all.

Comment: Have you created the indexes? Or are you asking prior to creating them?

Comment: 'InnoDB processes SELECT COUNT(*) statements by traversing the smallest available secondary index unless an index or optimizer hint directs the optimizer to use a different index. If a secondary index is not present, InnoDB processes SELECT COUNT(*) statements by scanning the clustered index.' -https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count note the SMALLEST